# objdump showing wrong start and end address for functions

Tags: elf, objdump, lld

For testing purposes, I modified the PLT stub that is generated by the llvm linker, [lld](https://lld.llvm.org/).

The stub before was:

```
 0xff, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // jmpq *got(%rip)
 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // pushq <relocation index>
 0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00        // jmpq plt[0]
```

Linking a program with this (original) stub and inspecting it with `objdump` yields something like this:

```
00000000002012d0 <printf@plt>:
  2012d0:   ff 25 62 0d 00 00       jmpq   *0xd62(%rip)        # 202038 <__TMC_END__+0x28>
  2012d6:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
  2012db:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   2012a0 <_fini+0x10>
```

I modified the PLT stub by simply adding a NOP at the end:

```
 0xff, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // jmpq *got(%rip)
 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // pushq <relocation index>
 0xe9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,       // jmpq plt[0]
 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x40, 0x00              // nop
```

I made sure to modify the `PltEntrySize` variable so that it reflects the change in size. Linking and running programs with this modification seems to work just fine.

However, when I try to inspect the disassembly of a linked program with `objdump`, I see something strange:

```
00000000002012d0 <printf@plt>:
  2012d0:   cc                      int3   
  2012d1:   ff                      (bad)  
  2012d2:   ff                      (bad)  
  2012d3:   ff 0f                   decl   (%rdi)
  2012d5:   1f                      (bad)  
  2012d6:   40 00 ff                add    %dil,%dil
  2012d9:   25 5a 0d 00 00          and    $0xd5a,%eax
  2012de:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
  2012e3:   e9 b8 ff ff ff          jmpq   2012a0 <_fini+0x10>
  2012e8:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

The PLT stub's address is interpreted by `objdump` to be at `0x2012d0`, but the real `printf@plt` address is at `0x2012d8`! This is confirmed by `readelf -s`:

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    ...
    6: 00000000002012d8     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
```

Where does `objdump` get its information from? It could very well be that I forgot to modify something in the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For testing purposes, I modified the PLT stub that is generated by the llvm linker, lld.

The size and layout of the `plt` entry is set in stone by the [ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) (see pg. 79), and can not be changed.

> Linking and running programs with this modification seems to work just fine.

I doubt any non-trivial program will run correctly with your modification -- the dynamic loader assumes ABI `plt` layout, and should crash and burn when given bogus `plt`.

Comment: Thanks, that is annoying. However I looked at the dynamic linker's source and it touches only the GOT, so it shouldn't be affected by changes in the PLT. I will test more, if it breaks I'll change my strategy. Objdump clearly assumes a fixed size for the PLT stub so it shows incorrect information.